# How to prevent reaching wicket page per url

Tags: java, security, wicket

I have a security issue. I have a menu, which allows or disallows user to go to a certain page. It is simple, if user is disallowed to reach page, link to it is being hidden in the menu.
But, user still can enter direct URL in browser, and can reach page.
For example, I have CardPage, per link I can reach it using

```
setResponsePage(new CardPage());
```

or

```
setResponsePage(CardPage.class);
```

but still I can reach this page entering such URL:

*http://127.0.0.1:8080/my-application-war/?wicket:bookmarkablePage=:com.my.application.CardPage*

Is there is any way to forbid user to access this page per URL?
I can give you additional info on that question if there is something you need.

**UPDATE**

Had to do it manually, check on every page if it is allowed to be seen, and redirect to NotAllowedPage.

Comment: Unless you use permissions per user or user's profile, I don't see how you can achieve this.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to track down, how you reached this page - per link or url?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, like using Spring Security or Apache Shiro. But if you don't need anything fancy, I would just go with the functionality that is provided by Wicket itself. Just read [Security with Wicket](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/8.x/single.html#_security_with_wicket) in the Wicket guide (which is by the way an excellence reference).

Comment: I`ll accept your answer, cause it is the only one, but it ain`t solved my problem. I already authenticate user to reach main application, but wanted to disable some pages. Made it manually, on every page constructor check if page can be seen, then redirect to notAllowedPage if it cannot.

Comment: The url is borken

Comment: @Zerlono: fixed